# How to put textout in an area?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Currently using canvas.textout in a TGraphicControl Component,  to show some text but i need the text to stay inside an area. Is there any property like word wrap i could use.. or a way to set the textout area? like so

```
var
  r: TRect
  s: string
begin
  s := 'some long text that takes up about 3-4 lines';
  r.Left := 10;
  r.Top := 10;
  r.Right := 20;
  r.bottom := 50;
  textout(r,s);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'This is some sample text. It is very long. Very long, indeed.' +
      'Very, very, long.';
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := Rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, S, length(S), R, DT_WORDBREAK);
end;
```

Comment: i guess i should add, i am drawing text on a tgraphiccontrol component.  would this still work?

Comment: @Glen: Yes, sure. Just replace `Canvas.Handle` by the actual HDC you want to draw on.

Comment: I would suggest to use `TCanvas.TextRect` which is a wrapper for the extented version of this Windows API function (or of `ExtTextOut` function in its overload) just because it's native for Delphi.

Comment: @Tlama, when i tried this , the text does not wrap onto the next line when it reaches the end of the Trect area... should it?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Same thing it seems to clip the text and not enter a new line when it reaches the end of the rect

Comment: @Glen: Did you forget `DT_WORDBREAK`?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand no its there, iam just dum :D  made the rect bottom value wrong..